# Mentor as a verb

Tags: prepositional-phrases

If someone is serving as my mentor, are they mentoring me AT something or FOR something?  I posed a question to someone else asking what a 3rd party could potentially mentor me at, hence the question

Answer (score 2):

***[Mentor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mentor)*** as a verb is both transitive and intransitive:

> - verb (used without object)***to act as a mentor:***
>
>   - *She spent years mentoring to junior employees.*
> - verb (used with object)
>     ***to act as a mentor to:***
>
>   - *The brash young executive did not wish to be mentored by anyone.*

(Dictionary.com)